# Getting an Error "gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound"

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Been trying to access Google Drive through Python using a service account. I am getting the above error continuously. Have looked up the existing documentation on the internet on this and have tried the below things

- added the service account email for giving access to the Excel spreadsheet
- added the service account email for giving access to the folder containing the spreadsheet
- specified the default scopes to include drive and spreadsheets
- enabled google drive and spreadsheet APIs
  The code is as given below

import gspread

default_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='D:\pythonProject\pythonProject\service_account.json',scopes=default_scopes)

sh = gc.open("TRNS")

print(sh.TRN.get('A1'))

Answer (score 0):

#### I think you have mixed up the sheet name and the spreadsheet

Modified snippet:

```py
ht1 = gc.open_by_key('YOUR SPREADSHEET ID') // REPLACE WITH YOUR ID
worksheet = sh.worksheet("Sheet1") // REPLACE WITH YOUR SHEET NAME
val = worksheet.acell('A1').value
print(val)
```

Be sure to replace the spreadsheet id with your actual ID.

#### Just in case

Spreadsheet ID:

[image]

Sheet name:

[image]

Comment: I used the spreadshht name, Will try the ID. thanks

Comment: Tried the above code. It did not work, but gave me another error. gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'This operation is not supported for this document', 'status': 'FAILED_PRECONDITION'}